# Installing LAPACK on OSX

Tags: c, gfortran, lapack

In installing LAPACK to use with C on OSX, I type "make" into the terminal and get the following:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C INSTALL run
./testlsame
make[1]: *** [run] Segmentation fault: 11
make: *** [lapack_install] Error 2
```

What do these errors mean and how do I get rid them?  I'm using Xcode 9.2 and just installed gfortran (maybe I did this wrong)?

Sorry for the very basic question.

Comment: OS X ships with LAPACK as part of Apple's [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate). The version is a bit outdated, but you could use that directly without installing anything. If you need a newer version, I'd really recommend [installing it](http://formulae.brew.sh/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-core/formula/lapack) [via Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: Thank you!  I just downloaded it in homebrew.  Do you know what this means?

  `This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into   /  usr/local,
    because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
    parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

    For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include
    For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig`

Comment: Usually, Homebrew links things into `/usr/local` so that they can be found by other software. This means that when you build other software, it may find this newer version of a package, while it's expecting to use Apple's version. This incompatibility can cause problems, so packages already provided by Apple are not automatically linked. The software installed fine, you just need to use those flags when you build new software that depends on the package.

Comment: So, how do I incorporate this in a c file?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To compile `file.c` which uses LAPACK routines: `gcc -o file file.c -I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/ -llapack`. To include this version of LAPACK in another project that would otherwise use the Apple-provided version: `make CPPFLAGS+="-I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include" LDFLAGS+="-L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib"`.

Comment: I'm still missing something.  I get the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LAPACKE_dgesv", referenced from:
      _main in test-4fb6b8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: I think you need to link using `-llapacke`, note the final "e" on that. LAPACK is written in Fortran, with LAPACKE being the name of the C bindings.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you bnaecker!  It compiles now!

Answer (score 2):

As @bnaeker correctly you have everything ready for use installed on your OSX. You do not need anything beyond specifying `-framework Accelerate` and you're done.